# How to find Z impedance if I have only S11 (db) and phase

Tags: impedance, s-parameters, reflection, vna

I need to measure Z line impedance. Using VNA I measured S11 it is -53.8785 dB and phase at this point is 175.6706.

Could you explain using these numbers how to find R and jR

S11 = (Zx-Z0)/(Zx+z0) = -48.1777939889323
I calculate it and I received a negative number how could it be?

Kind regards

[image: S11 from the VNA]

Comment: Do you know what the S11 represents? And the formula that relates S11, line impedance, and load impedance?

Comment: I do not know line impedance. I want to find it. The output of VNA is 50 ohm. S11 is the return loss, it shows the difference between the level of the output signal to reflected signal and it is shown in negative values -db.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Suggestion: start with the *definition* of S11 and work backward from that. Also remember that S-parameters are not the only ones (I remember about 5 families of them but there are more) and there are ways to convert between them. S-parameters are mostly used because they are the *easiest to measure*

Answer (score 2):

Careful now! Whilst the previous answer is *mathematically* correct - what you are *actually* measuring is the combination of the output match (S22) of your instrument *and* the input match of the unit under test.

https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/vswr-mismatch.htm

Mismatch uncertainty error is often overlooked by even the most experienced engineers and scientists and is why we use very expensive metrology grade connectors and cabling.

Answer (score 0):

\$S_{11}\$ is the return loss of an input port and, is related to reflection coefficient (\$\Gamma\$) like this: -

$$S_{11} = -20\log(|\Gamma|)$$

In other words, it's the magnitude of \$\Gamma\$ that is used in the formula and, you can't convert \$S_{11}\$ into an unambiguous impedance. Here's a link ([microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/voltage-standing-wave-ratio-vswr)) that may help: -

[image]